# ¿Como crear un trigger en MySQL que actualice la fecha final de una membresía sumandole meses a partir de la fecha de inicial?

Tags: mysql-workbench, trigger, sintaxis

Estoy intentando crear un trigger para actualizar la fecha final a partir de la fecha inicial de una membresia, sumandole un numero de meses a la fecha inicial y guardando el resultado en el campo fecha final de la tabla RegistrosMembresias.

Tengo estas tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE Membresias (
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Nombre VARCHAR(50),
DuracionMeses INT,
Precio DECIMAL(8, 2)
);


CREATE TABLE RegistrosMembresias (
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
ClienteID INT,
MembresiaID INT,
FechaInicio DATE,
FechaFin DATE,
FOREIGN KEY (ClienteID) REFERENCES Clientes(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (MembresiaID) REFERENCES Membresias(ID)
);
```

He intentado con esto para el Trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER actualiza_fecha_fin
BEFORE INSERT ON RegistrosMembresias
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF New.MembresiaID = '1' THEN
SET NEW.FechaFin = DATE_ADD (NEW.FechaInicio, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
ELSEIF NEW.MembresiaID = '2' THEN
SET NEW.FechaFin = DATE_ADD (NEW.FechaInicio, INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
ELSE IF NEW.MembresiaID = '3' THEN
SET NEW.FechaFin = DATE_ADD (NEW.FechaInicio, INTERVAL 12 MONTH);
END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hola. MySQL no permite programar `TRIGGER` que modifiquen a la misma tabla que los dispara. Dicho eso, no le veo sentido a tener unos datos muertos si con el valor del ID ya sabes cuánto debe durar cada membresía. Simplemente, calcula in situ, allí donde lo necesites.

Answer (score 0):

El error  lo tienes al sumar los meses, con la función `DATE_ADD ()` que no puede llevar ese espacio entre el nombre de la función y los paréntesis. En cualquier caso, puedes usar `INTERVAL` directamente sin `DATE_ADD()`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualiza_fecha_fin
BEFORE INSERT ON RegistrosMembresias
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF New.MembresiaID = '1' THEN
    SET NEW.FechaFin = NEW.FechaInicio + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
  ELSEIF NEW.MembresiaID = '2' THEN
      SET NEW.FechaFin = NEW.FechaInicio + INTERVAL 6 MONTH;
  ELSEIF NEW.MembresiaID = '3' THEN
      SET NEW.FechaFin = NEW.FechaInicio + INTERVAL 12 MONTH;
  END IF;
END;
```

Para que el disparador te quede un poco más dinámico, es mejor que lea los plazos de membresía directamente de la tabla en la que los estás almacenando y así evitas los `IF`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualiza_fecha_fin
BEFORE INSERT ON RegistrosMembresias
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.FechaFin = NEW.FechaInicio + INTERVAL (
    SELECT DuracionMeses FROM Membresias
      WHERE ID = NEW.MembresiaID
  ) MONTH;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.